# Return the function names from an R script in a package as a vector

Tags: r

I am creating an R package which will have a script called metrics.R inside the R folder and this script will contain a lot of summary metrics. Now I want to be able to view these metrics as a vector as i already have a function which can take this vector to create a summary table with each new column being the name of a function within the vector.

The reason i would like to have this function is i want a dynamic list of metrics for users to select and i don't want to have to update this every time i add a new metric.

I have tried the following code.

```
available_metrics <- function(loc = "metrics.R"){

  location <- paste0(system.file(package = "my_package_name"), "/R/", loc)

  temp_env <- new.env()

  # Source the script into the temporary environment
  source(location, local = temp_env)

  # Get all objects from the temporary environment
  all_objects <- ls(temp_env)

  # Extract function names
  function_names <- sapply(all_objects, function(obj_name) {
    obj <- get(obj_name, envir = temp_env)
    if (is.function(obj)) return(obj_name)
    else return(NULL)
  })

  # Turn into vector and filter out this function.
  function_names <- as.vector(function_names[!sapply(function_names, is.null)])
  function_names <- function_names[!function_names == "available_metrics"]

  return(function_names)
}
```

If i do load_all() this works but when i install the package and try from a fresh session I recieved an unable to open file: No such file or directory error. I wondered if anyone can help with this. Thanks,

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by `dynamic list of metrics`?

Why not simply create a list object in your package that will contain the function names of all metrics? Sure, you will have to manually update it every time you add a new metric to your package, but that seems like extra 5 seconds of much simpler code.

Comment: If you look at how a package directory hierarchy looks after installation, its `./R/` folder doesn't contain the original `.R` files. I suggest you look at `list.files(system.file("R", package="dplyr"))` (as an example, any package will do) to see the files present.

Comment: But your initial need and premise are unclear to me. Since you're creating a package, why do you need to source the contents of a different `.R` file to get the structure for what you need? Can you provide a _brief_ example of what your `metrics.R` contains? Perhaps you should move the file under `inst/`, since files in that subdirectory will be moved to the top-level of an installed package.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply both of you. The metrics file contains a list of functions with general metrics and specific metrics for author verification results i.e. general like 'accuracy', 'precision' etc. and more specific like 'F1', 'F0.5u'. So I just wanted the user to be able to see what functions were contained in this script.

Comment: But i get that it's probably easier to manually add to a list as I go, just wondered if it was possible to do this automatically.

Comment: The easiest way (besides hard-coding the vector of the functions, which is [what I would do](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/b386bac4d7269f989f63c1fd650e8be464dd44ed/R/paths.r#L231-L232)) is to define all these functions in their own local environment, or use a fixed naming schema for the functions, e.g. by prefixing them all with a common prefix (afterwards it’s just a matter of using `ls(pattern = …)` to find the function names).

Comment: Yet another solution is to use Rd/Roxygen2 annotations on these functions, in particular the `@keywords` tag, which can be used to categorise functions into groups. You can query these groups at runtime: `hsearch = readRDS(readRDS(system.file('Meta/hsearch.rds', package = .packageName)))`, and then `merge(hsearch[[2L]], hsearch[[3L], 'ID')[, c('Alias', 'Keyword')]`. This will give you a matrix with function names and tags.